# google auth works in production apk but not works after launching the app on play store in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, authentication, ionic2, google-plus-signin

1.The application was build in Ionic 2
2. For implementing the google auth Cordova-plugin-google plus is used
3. The app works fine before launching on play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your SHA1 key.

**How to Get Android Release Keystore SHA1 Fingerprint**

1. Open terminal.
2. Change the directory to the JDK bin directory,

   **cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk{Version}\bin**
3. Next you have to run the keytool.exe. Use the following line to get the SHA1 fingerprint.

   **keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}**
4. Enter the password, you will get the SHA1 and MD5 fingerprint.

**Change SHA1**

5. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
6. Choose your project -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs
7. Click on android client id
8. Replace SHA1 here and save it

I hope it works for you.